# What is the relation between dimension and Quantum Field Theory? How does different dimensions change QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, spacetime-dimensions

Does the quantisation rules & field operators for scalar or Dirac fields change with dimension? Most books wrote about 3 spatial dimensions, and then upgraded it to 4 spacetime dimensions, keeping it Lorentz invariant. But, what about 2 dimensions? Or 6 dimensions? Is there a generalised QFT for all dimensions, like a master equation or set of equations?

Comment: Replace $4$ with $d$ everywhere and you're done. Renormalizability might change, but the theory is pretty much the same.

Comment: What about lorentz invariance and gauge invariance? Will we check it for every dimension individually?

Comment: Your Lorentz group just becomes $\mathrm{SO}(d-1,1)$ instead of $\mathrm{SO}(3,1)$. The analysis and definition of "spinors" becomes a pain in higher dimensions, but I'm not sure what you're looking for here, most QFT methods do not use the specific dimension we are in , and pointing out *everything* that is (slightly) different for general dimensions is definitely *too broad*.

Comment: Ofcourse. I am not asking anyone to write a thesis on it. Just some ideas will do. And thanks for all the comments.